# How do you access Markmail

Tags: marklogic

This is probably off-topic for SO, but [Markmail](https://developer.marklogic.com/code/markmail/) has yielded nothing but "refused to connect" for more than a week, [isitdown](https://www.isitdownrightnow.com/markmail.org.html) shows a general outage, and Marklogic tech support has not responded to queries from registered customers.

Any hints for a more appropriate forum for finding out what's going on with the server?

Comment: What do you mean about support not responding to questions?

Answer (score 3):

https://markmail.org has been permanently shut down and will no longer be available.